# polyline in rails using js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm trying to draw simple polylines in js (rails) but it ain't showing anything.

```
function drawlines()
{
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#ff0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 25,
    map:map
    });

flightPath.setMap(map);
console.log('drawn');
}
```

Comment: What is "map" variable in your code? See how var map is declared here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Comment: Do you see any errors in JS console? Also, that code is missing some context.

Comment: Polyline on map is not showing, or entire map is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code. In your code, you don't need to use the settings the map:map.

Try this code

```
function drawlines(){

        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#ff0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 25,

        });
        flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```